# calculating risk free interest rate from put call parity

Tags: options, interest-rates, put-call-parity

I'm trying to calculate the interest rate $r$ from the put-call parity.
As per hull, put-call parity is given by the below equation.

$c + Ke^{-rT} = p + S_{0}$

where:
$c$ = current call option price with stike=$K$
$p$ = current put option price with stike=$K$
$K$ = stirke price
$S_{0}$ = spot price
$r$ = annualized risk free interest rate
$T$ = time till expiry in years

To calculate $r$ we can re-write the equation as\

$r$ = $-\frac {ln( \frac {p + S_{0} - c}{K})} {T}$

I'm trying to validate this against market data. I've below values from real market data
$K$ = 10000
$c$ = 428.4
$p$ = 466.5
$S_{0}$ = 10107.6
$T$ = 13 days = (13/365)
$F_{0}$ = 9961.5 (current future price)

when I  plug these values into the equation I'm getting an interest rate of $-40.61\text{%}$.
Am I missing something? These options contracts were liquid with a good bid-ask spread.

I also verify that $c - p + k = F_{0} $

Comment: $F_0$ is below $S_0$. Is this a dividend paying asset? Are these options on the asset or options on the future?

Comment: @noob2 Options are index options

Comment: F=9961.5 and S=10107.6 suggests a dividend of 1.4% in the next 13 days, which seems too large (40% annual dividend yield). There is something about these numbers I do not understand...